# No sound over HDMI with WindowsIoT icw Pi3

Tags: audio, hdmi, windows-iot, pi-3

Using WindowsIoT on the Raspberry Pi 3 I tried playing sound/video from a c# application. The video plays, however the sound is played over the 3.5mm jack instead of over HDMI. It's an older TV, so maybe it isn't detected automatically, but the TV does have speakers.

How can I switch the sound output from jack to HDMI with WindowsIoT like you can switch it with Raspbian?

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that you cannot set a default audio device in Windows IoT so that applications can use this as a guideline to choose a device for playback. [This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1bdd0dd5-12cb-4fc0-86eb-2d2c7c6e569e/how-to-select-audio-device?forum=WindowsIoT) and some others point this out indirectly.

Your C# application has to enumerate all devices and choose the correct one. If you have access to the source, then the link above contains a reference to an example on how to do this.

Comment: I looked into it, but couldn't find a solution. All I want to do is play some sound from a MediaElement in a Universal Windows app. The link you provided talks about AudioGraphs and input/output nodes. Looks way to complicated to achieve a simple sound being played from an internet radio stream. I did look into it quickly, but couldn't figure out how to specify the input for the AudioGraph. Examples only play from a local audio file. You have any experience on this subject?